# Adding new rating elements via input using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 5 rating circles with special functionality. How to add new elements by changing `max-value="5"` attribute by setting a number into input and clicking on a button. Also I need to save all existing functionality and apply it to new adding elements as if they were there before (maybe using `delegate` method).

For example: you type number 7, click button (`max-value` attribute changes from 5 to 7), and 2 circles adds to existing 5 ones, and everything continues to work as before.

P.S. HTML and CSS cannot be modified. Also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1akg9z7L/) is fiddle version.

```js
$(function() {

  // Frequently used variable:
  var item = $('.rating-circle');
  var container = $('#rating-container');

  // Rating-hover effects:
  item.hover(function() {
    $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().toggleClass('rating-hover');
  });

  container.on('mouseout', function() {
    item.each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('data-chosen') == '1') {
        $(this).addClass('rating-chosen');
      }
    });
  });

  container.on('mouseover', function() {
    item.removeClass('rating-chosen');
  });

  // Rating-chosen effects:
  var chosen = item.click(function() {
    chosen.removeClass('rating-chosen').prop('data-chosen', '0');
    $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().addClass('rating-chosen').prop('data-chosen', '1');
  });

});


$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#update-max-value', function1);
});

function function1() {
  $('#rating-container').append('<div class="rating-circle"></div>');
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}

.rating-circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: .1em solid black;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1em;
}

.rating-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rating-chosen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Rate this session</h3>
<div id="rating-container" max-value="5">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="max-value">Enter max value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="max-value" />
  <button type="button" id="update-max-value">Update max value</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1akg9z7L/)

```
$(
start = function () {

// Frequently used variable:
var item = $('.rating-circle');
var container = $('#rating-container');

// Rating-hover effects:
item.hover(function () {
    $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().toggleClass('rating-hover');
});

container.on('mouseout', function () {
    item.each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('data-chosen') == '1') {
            $(this).addClass('rating-chosen');
        }
    });
});

container.on('mouseover', function () {
    item.removeClass('rating-chosen');
});

// Rating-chosen effects:
var chosen = item.click(function () {
    chosen.removeClass('rating-chosen').prop('data-chosen', '0');
    $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().addClass('rating-chosen').prop('data-chosen', '1');
});

$(document).on('click', '#update-max-value', function1);
});

function function1 () {
    var n = $('#max-value').val();
    var txt = '';
    $('#rating-container').attr('max-value', n);
    for( var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        txt += '<div class="rating-circle"></div>';
    };
    $('#rating-container').html(txt);
    start();

};
```

Comment: Btw, why we need to use  `txt` variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```js
$(function() {

  // Frequently used variable:
  var item = $('.rating-circle');
  var container = $('#rating-container');

  // Rating-hover effects:
  container.on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.rating-circle', function(e) {
    $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().toggleClass('rating-hover', e.type == 'mouseenter');
  }).on('click', '.rating-circle', function() {
    container.find('.rating-chosen').removeClass('rating-chosen');
    $(this).prevAll('.rating-circle').andSelf().addClass('rating-chosen');
  });

});


$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#update-max-value', function1);
});

function function1() {
  var $circles = $('#rating-container .rating-circle');
  var value = +$('#max-value').val() || 0;

  $('#rating-container').attr('max-value', value);
  if ($circles.length < value) {
    $('#rating-container').append(new Array(value - $circles.length + 1).join('<div class="rating-circle"></div>'));
  } else if ($circles.length > value) {
    $circles.slice(value).remove()
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}
.rating-circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: .1em solid black;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1em;
}
#rating-container:hover .rating-chosen {
  background-color: white;
}
.rating-hover,
#rating-container:hover .rating-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.rating-chosen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Rate this session</h3>
<div id="rating-container" max-value="5">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="max-value">Enter max value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="max-value" />
  <button type="button" id="update-max-value">Update max value</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it breaks existing functionality after 'input editing' by number.

Comment: @kirbrown which functionality is broken

Comment: Existing one, hover and click events after modifying the 5 circles by another number.

Comment: @kirbrown didn't understand the case.... but since you have got your answer it is irrelevant now